# MySQL count in same table including zero count values

Tags: mysql, count

I have this table structure with data:

```
INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `email`, `id_user_ref`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'email@gmail.com', NULL, 'Mike'),
(2, 'email2@gmail.com', '1', 'Jhonny'),
(3, 'email3@gmail.com', '1', 'Michael'),
(4, 'email4@gmail.com', '2', 'Jorhe'),
(5, 'email5@gmail.com', '3', 'Mia');
```

I need to count the id_user_ref for all users with this query:

```
SELECT id, COUNT(name) AS refNr FROM test GROUP BY id_user_ref
HAVING id_user_ref IS NOT NULL;
```

This works but the problem is that i need to display all results even if the count result is 0.

I tried several left joins with the same table but without any success.

The output should be:

```
id  refNr
1    2
2    1
3    1
4    0
5    0
```

Comment: you want to count how many users mike invited? then you will run into a inner join from the table to itself :-)

Comment: What is the desired output you want to get from this query?

Comment: i need to know how for every person how many persons have their id ref including 0

Comment: i added the expected result to the question

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  t1.id, 
  IFNULL(COUNT(t2.name), 0) AS refNr 
FROM test AS t1
LEFT JOIN test AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id_user_ref
GROUP BY t1.id;
```

[**SQL Fiddle DEmo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ce037/3)

This will give you:

```
| ID | REFNR |
--------------
|  1 |     2 |
|  2 |     1 |
|  3 |     1 |
|  4 |     0 |
|  5 |     0 |
```

Comment: `ON t1.id = t2.id_user_ref` doesnt makes any sense to me. These columns arnt the same!?

Comment: @C4ud3x - The column `id` is the id of the user, the column `id_user_ref` is a reference id to the `id` column, the user is looking for a way to get the count of the referenced ids by each `id` with 0 for those who don't have a reference. So the way to do this is to `LEFT JOIN` the same table, like what I did in my query.

Comment: Aaah now I got it! Thanks for explaining :).

Comment: This one works for me, even if I've no idea what's going on.... I think I need to learn more about LEFT JOIN...

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this ?

```
SELECT a.id,
CASE  WHEN b.refNr IS NULL THEN 0
ELSE b.refNr END FROM test a LEFT JOIN
( SELECT id_user_ref, COUNT(name) AS refNr
    FROM test
    WHERE id_user_ref IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY id_user_ref) b
ON a.id = b.id_user_ref
```

[Sql Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ce037/14)