# Find existence of a record in MySQL table with input data as a list

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a list of ids in text format as a comma separated value like so
("12345", "12346", "12347", etc, etc)

I would like to find their existence or non existence from a table say devices table which has a column called device ids (not primary key)

Ideally i would like to get a list which says if each item exists or not.

So far I have tried to get the query of those that exist and I have to manually find the non existing ones.

Is there a for loop I have to run on stored procedures or something like that. Please help.

Table structure

```html
<pre>
| id   | device_id       | device_name   |
+------+-----------------+---------------+
|   71 | 352701060409650 | 57X           |
|   13 | 352701060409700 | 582           |
</pre>
```

Comment: please share your table structure and expected output in detail

Comment: table columns : id, device_id, device_name, register_status .................I have a list of device_ids that I got from somewhere. I need to check for each item in that list, if it exists in the table or not. Expected output a list of device_ids with a 0 or a 1 for exist or not exist.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a query with left join to the same table with 'IFNULL' condition. There already has been a post for this topic. Please check this out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15758201/mysql-count-in-same-table-including-zero-count-values).